# Duda con un select multiple

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Consulto porque tengo una duda, por ahi me pueden ayudar con información (después me arreglo)... quiero poner en un formulario, un select, que a medida que el usuario vaya eligiendo items, se vayan mostrando como "etiquetas" en la cabecera del select... mas o menos como queda en esta misma página cuando se coloca una pregunta y abajo en etiquetas van quedando con una "X" para eliminarlas... 
He estado buscando pero realmente no se como decirle a san google qué buscar, aparte no se si será muy complejo de colocar en el formulario...

Comment: Por favor pasa por [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Añade el código que lleves intentado hasta ahora, por favor.

Comment: Básicamente, deberías:
 
1) Encontrar/Realizar un control html como el que quieres insertar.

2) Determinar dónde se va a insertar éste nuevo elemento (un div pequeño sobre el select, por ejemplo).

3) Capturar el Evento que se desencadena al seleccionar un option.

4) En el evento, tomar el valor del option, y a partir de eso, crear tu elemento para insertar en la cabecera.

5) Insertar el Elemento en el Div.

Para todo ésto podrías usar Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes hacer uso de BootstrapSelect desde el siguiente enlace https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#selected-text-format

y usar el codigo de ejemplo

```
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option value="1">Mustard</option>
  <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="3">Relish</option>
</select>
```

El usuario podra elegir cuantos elementos desee y  esto te genera un arreglo ["1","2","3"], los cuales ya podras almacenar o usar de la mejor manera.

Puedes encontrar mas informacion en la pagina web del desarrollador https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: UN MILLON DE GRACIAS JESUS... !!! ME VOY A PONER A INVESTIGAR... GRACIAS NUEVAMENTE

Comment: porque un -1? :(

Comment: yo quiero calificarte con +1 pero todavía no me deja calificar... alguien calificó con ese valor (y no soy yo) !!!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el plugin [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#select-boxes-with-labels) el cual contiene muchas opciones útiles para lo que necesitas

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
   <p>Select Multiple</p>
     <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Juan. Por favor brinda más detalle en la respuesta sobre cómo este plugin puede ayudar a resolver el problema planteado.

Comment: Ok, gracias, editado y mejorado un poco

Comment: que bueno que esta !!! gracias por el dato !!!